Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds by Lee: Problem Suggestions
I am planning to self-study Riemannian Manifold/Geometry using the textbook stated in the title next semester. I self-studied topological manifolds using Introduction to Topological Manifolds by the same author using this syllabus: https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Elee/Courses/544-2019/hw.html. Currently I am learning smooth manifolds using Introduction to Smooth Manifolds (again by the same author) and will probably finish all the chapters except the chapters 13, 19, 20, 21, and 22.
I know this question is answered for topological manifolds and smooth manifolds by this post Introduction to Topological Manifolds: Problem Suggestions, and I should ideally do all of the problems, but I wanted to know which problems are important? Ideally, I want about 5-12 problems for each chapter.
Additionally, which topics should I read. In the preface, there are some topics that the author says can be omitted on first reading. I never taken a differential geometry class, so I don't know if I should omit them because some of them looks important, e.g. Gauss-Bonnet Theorem.

As I've been going through those books I prioritized the problems that were referred to in the main text or in other problems (Lee usually indicates this). These could cover missing steps in some proof or provide good counterexamples, so I think they are important. Then I do additional problems that seem interesting. If I get stuck on some problems for too long or I don't find them interesting, I skip them.

For what it's worth, here are the problems I assigned the last time I taught a course from that book:
2-2, 2-4, 2-6, 2-7, 3-3, 3-10, 3-12, 3-18, 3-19, 4-6, 4-9, 5-4, 5-5, 5-6, 5-8, 5-10, 6-5, 6-14, 7-13, 8-3, 8-5, 8-15, 8-16, 8-17, 8-18, 10-7, 10-23, 11-4, 12-1, 12-2, 12-13
In addition, I asked the students to work out the following problems on their own, but not to hand in for grading:
2-1, 2-9, 2-10, 3-2, 3-5, 3-11, 4-1, 4-2, 4-3, 4-11, 5-3, 5-11, 6-1, 6-13, 6-21, 7-1, 7-2, 8-11, 8-14, 8-29, 10-1, 10-3, 10-11, 10-24, 12-3, 12-6
